# The accurate modelling of a xbox controller

Tags: modeling, objects

I started modelling about 2 weeks ago, and I was looking forward to expend the tools that are in the bedroom, I modelled. I am currently working on a project -it is a controller I tried using blueprints that I obtained from a website-, and I could really use some assistance from the members of this community. Things seemed to be going smoothly as I followed the blueprints, but I encountered a challenge when attempting to manipulate the vertices. It resulted in a messy outcome. I hope that someone with expertise in modeling can provide me with guidance, tips, or even a step-by-step tutorial, to accurately model a controller. I attached some images, so you can understand what I am talking about.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't plan to build a submarine   :p

Answer (score 6):

Duplicate your reference image in order to have a proper top, side and front view:

[image]

Begin by drawing the most characteristic shape, which seems to be the top view:

[image]

Then switch to the side view, extrude up:

[image]

Bend the shape, add an edge loop and move its vertices:

[image]

In front view, move up the middle bottom:

[image]

You'll need to lift a bit the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I literally copied everything you did, and of course it worked. Thank you fopr that, although I have some additional questions. when you created the top part, you added more edges, and created a face with it. how did you know where to put those edges? Or are you just like "I want the faces to have exactly 4 edges, so here, here, and here" ?

Comment: Thanks but I've realized that the shape is actually not accurate because the bottom doesn't look like this but it was hard to guess with the blueprint only, I'll try to correct that. As for your question, I put the edges a bit randomly then I can add if necessary or dissolve the useless one

Comment: naah, let it go my man, I'll deal with the bottom part (I didn't even realize it was problematic). Thank you for the tips, and the advices, I really appreciate it! <33